# Default Size of a Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to programmatically pull the default size (height and width) of a Form that I am creating. I am trying to use the `Control.DefaultSize` Property of the CONTROL class.
Now this property returns a value of type `Size`, which is a structure in the `System.Drawing` namespace. Hence to store the value returned by this property I have declared a `Size` type variable named `store`.

Once that happens I wanted to print out the width and height properties of this structure type variable. That was my idea but its clearly not working as I am getting error in the `store = form1.DeafultSize()` statement.
Can anyone tell how to make this work?

The code that I wrote:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim form1 As New Form()
        Dim store As System.Drawing.Size
        store = form1.DeafultSize() 'Error coming in this line
        Console.WriteLine("Default Height of Form: {0}", store.Height)
        Console.WriteLine("Default Width of Form: {0}", store.Width)
        Application.Run(form1)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Form.DefaultSize](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,1148) is a property, not a method, it's `protected` - so you can access it only from a derived class or through reflection.
It's set by default to `new Size(300, 300)` in a Form (as you can see in the .Net Source code).

The Control class doesn't really define a `DefaultSize` value, [it's virtual](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,2217) (`Overridable`), it just returns `Size.Empty`, it's an implementation-specific value (classes that implement Control define their own value overriding the Property).

If you want to know what is the Size assigned by default to your Form object, just read it:

```
Dim form1 As New Form()
Dim store = form1.Size
```